# Casting a string to Date and Time in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have a table in GreenPlum (PostgreSQL) with all fields as sting, and I want to edit the types :

To do this I created a view :

```
CREATE VIEW typed_view AS

SELECT CAST(sid AS bigint), CAST(gid AS bigint),
```

...

But I have a problem with the Date and Time fields, I tried this command but it didn't work :

```
 to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(eventdatetime,"yyyy-MM-dd
```

HH:mm:ss")),'UTC') AS eventdatetime,

After that I tried the PostgreSQL notation :

```
to_timestamp(eventdatetime, 'YYYY Mon DD HH24 MI SS') AS eventdatetime,
```

But still not working.

Anyone knows how to convert it ?

I also have this command that is not working :

```
CASE WHEN fix = "True" THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS fix,
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide example data so I'm going to assume your data looks like "YYYY Mon DD HH24 MI SS".  So January 4, 2016 at 2:15:20 PM would look like '2016 Jan 04 14 15 20' in your data.  So with this example data, the conversion would look like this:

```
gpadmin=# select to_timestamp('2016 Jan 04 14 15 20', 'yyyy mon dd hh24 mi ss') as col1;
          col1          
------------------------
 2016-01-04 14:15:20-05
(1 row)
```

Now this is a timestamp which also include the timezone offset which for my server is -5.  To convert this to a timestamp without the timezone, you just add ::timestamptz.

```
gpadmin=# select to_timestamp('2016 Jan 04 14 15 20', 'yyyy mon dd hh24 mi ss')::timestamp as col1;
        col1         
---------------------
 2016-01-04 14:15:20
(1 row)
```

A very important note on this.  It is costly to convert data from a string to a different datatype. That is the same in all databases too.  It is better to incur the expense of this conversion once rather than doing it for every SELECT statement.  So, I also suggest you materialize this transformation into a physical table rather than using a VIEW.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The goal is to create a VIEW in Greenplum because it's quick, and after the type convesion I create the table to load it in R : create table msgs as select * from msgs_typed_view.

As for the date format, it looks like this :  2013-05-26 23:59:54

Comment: Your string value is "2013-05-26 23:59:54"?  If so, that is an easy conversion.  select '2013-05-26 23:59:54'::timestamp;  Just add ::timestamp or ::timestamptz if you want the timezone.